# JSON Exception String cannot be converted to JSON Object

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse json and running into a small problem.

my json string looks like this:

```
String json =
    [
        "{caption=blah, url=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140331_164648.jpg}",
        "{caption=adsf, url=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140330_103412.jpg}"
    ]
```

and my code so far looks like this:

```
try {
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(json);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);



    String img = c.getString("url");
    String cap = c.getString("caption");
```

But its throwing an exception `type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If its helpful to anyone, I ended up using GSON to get my json in the correct expected format like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(mylist);
```

Comment: You used the line `getJSONObject` but you aren't trying to get a JSONObject, you are trying to get a String.

Comment: The jSON string is not properly of JSON format

Comment: try jsonlint.com to test your JSON

Comment: may you want your json to look like `[{"caption": "blah","url": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140331_164648.jpg"}`

Comment: @FaisalAli I did, Its valid as a whole but as Sotirios states below its just not in the format I expected

Comment: @BluGeni its a valid json but i don't think you want it that way. coz its a string. there is no json object there

Comment: @Raghunandan Is there a better way to convert an arraylist like this ` public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); ` to a json string with objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON array contains elements like

```
"{caption=blah, url=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140331_164648.jpg}"
```

which is a `String` not a JSON object. You can't therefore try to retrieve it as a `JSONObject`.

Seems like you're getting JSON that isn't in the [format](http://www.json.org/) you expected. Even if you got rid of the `""` around it, it still wouldn't be valid JSON, so I don't understand its purpose enough to help you.

Comment: Is there a better way to convert an arraylist like this ` public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
` to a json string with objects?

Comment: @BluGeni That Java object maps well to JSON like `[{"":""}, ...]`. In other words a JSON array that contains JSON objects. Each JSON object is a name-value pair of `String`s.